# TypeError: produce() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linger_ms'

Tags: python, django, apache-kafka, pykafka

I'm trying to use kafka with python with pykafka , when i try to use linger_ms i get this error :

TypeError: produce() got an unexpected keyword argument 'linger_ms'

This is my code :

```
import queue
from pykafka import KafkaClient
client = KafkaClient(hosts="127.0.0.1:9092,127.0.0.1:9093",broker_version="1.0.0")
topic = client.topics['mytopic']

with topic.get_producer(delivery_reports=True) as producer:
     count = 0
     while True:
         count += 1
         producer.produce(
             'test msg'.encode(encoding='UTF-8'), 
             partition_key=('{}'.format(count))
                          .encode(encoding='UTF-8'),
             timestamp=(datetime.datetime.now())+timedelta(seconds=120),
             linger_ms=120000)
```

Comment: 1. Format your code. 2. We will need the definition of `producer.produce`(if you defined it) or the package it's imported from.

Comment: Look up the documentation of the `produce()` method, apparently `linger_ms` isn't an argument for that method.

Comment: Well looking at the docs linger_ms is valid argument for class: [`pykafka.producer.Producer`](https://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/producer.html?highlight=linger#module-pykafka.producer). Maybe you need `producer.Produce(...)`

Comment: No it's not, the method `produce()` on a `Producer` does not accept a `linger_ms` argument, see [here](https://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/producer.html#pykafka.producer.Producer.produce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`produce()` method](https://pykafka.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/producer.html#pykafka.producer.Producer.produce) on a `Producer` does not take a `linger_ms` argument. That's why you get this error.

Pass the `linger_ms` argument when you initialise the `Producer`:

```
with topic.get_producer(delivery_reports=True, linger_ms=120000) as producer:
    ...
```